# Passing char pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

Okay so I am trying to pass a char pointer to another function. I can do this with an array of a char but cannot do with a char pointer. Problem is I don't know the size of it so I cannot declare anything about the size within the `main()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ptrch ( char * point) {
    point = "asd";
}

int main() {
    char * point;
    ptrch(point);
    printf("%s\n", point);
    return 0;
}
```

This does not work however, these two works:

1)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char * point;
    point = "asd";
    printf("%s\n", point);
    return 0;
}
```

2)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ptrch ( char * point) {
    strcpy(point, "asd");
}

int main() {
    char point[10];
    ptrch(point);
    printf("%s\n", point);
    return 0;
}
```

So I am trying to understand the reason and a possible solution for my problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
void ptrch ( char * point) {
    point = "asd";
}
```

Your pointer is **passed by value**, and this code **copies, then overwrites the copy**. So the original pointer is untouched.

P.S. Point to be noted that when you do `point = "blah"` you are creating a string literal, and any attempt to **modify** is **Undefined behaviour**, so it should really be **`const char *`**

**To Fix** - pass a **pointer to a pointer** as @Hassan TM does, or **return the pointer** as below.

```
const char *ptrch () {
    return "asd";
}

...
const char* point = ptrch();
```

Comment: Which way is less expensive?

Comment: @SarpKaya both are blazingly fast (difference would be minimal if any), but I would prefer the "return the pointer" method for readability.

Comment: This will trigger a warning of local variables if you do not hardcode the return value as a string literal.

Comment: why we need const here?

Answer (score 22):

This should work since pointer to the char pointer is passed. Therefore any changes to the pointer will be seen outside thereafter.

```
void ptrch ( char ** point) {
    *point = "asd";
}

int main() {
    char * point;
    ptrch(&point);
    printf("%s\n", point);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would have prefered to return the pointer rather than another level of indirection, but +1 nonetheless

Comment: why it works with integer and doesn't need to pass pointer to pointer? i think because after dereference, char pointer remain is the address of first element of array?

Answer (score 3):

Here:

`int main() {
char * point;
ptrch(point);`

You're passing `point` by value.  Then, `ptrch` sets its own local copy of `point` to point to `"asd"`, leaving the `point` in `main` untouched.

A solution would be to pass a pointer to `main`'s `point`:

`void ptrch(char **pp) { *pp = "asd"; return; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you change the value of the pointer in a function, it will remain changed only in that one function call.
Don't mess your head with pointers and try:

```
void func(int i){
  i=5;
}
int main(){
  int i=0;
  func(i);
  printf("%d\n",i);
  return 0;
}
```

The same with your pointer. You do **not** change the address it points to.

If you assign to a variable passed by value, the variable outside the function will remain unchanged.
You could pass it by a pointer (**to pointer**) and change it by dereferrencing it and it's the same with an int - in this case, it doesn't matter if the type is int or char * .

Answer (score -1):

first declare funtion......like this

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 void function_call(char s)
```

next write main code.....

```
void main()
{
    void (*pnt)(char);  //  pointer function declaration....
    pnt=&function_call;  //    assign address of function
    (*pnt)('b');   //   call funtion....
}
```