# How to manipulate variable in function?

Tags: c, pointers

In the example below, I pass a char into a function as a pointer. When the function prints out the memory address of the char, it is a different address. Am I dealing with two different variables in this case? Isn't that the same result as if I didn't use a pointer in the function argument (same as pass by value)?

```
char a = 'a';
printf("a=%p\n", &a);
showString(a);

//function 
void showString(char *c){
  c='b';
  printf("c=%p\n", &c);
}
```

`c` is assigned the value 'b'. But if I check `a` after the function call, it still has the value 'a'. How does the above need to change so the value assigned in the function carries over outside of the function?

Comment: You are printing `a`'s *address*, but you are passing its *value* to your function.  Incidentally, your compiler should be warning you about an implicit integer-to-pointer conversion; if it isn't then turn up the warning level.

Comment: "When the function prints out the memory address of the char," ---> the function is attempting to print the address of a `char *`, not the address of a `char`.

Comment: There is already a thread on this topic that can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331411/passing-char-pointer-in-c

Comment: With one substitution of the `*` with a `&`, the syntax you tried to use is how references would work if you were using C++. But you're not: you're using C and pointers. So using the address-of and dereference operators is mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function should look like

```
//function 
void showString(char *c) {
    *c = 'b';
    printf("c=%p\n", &c); //<---to print the address of C
    printf("c=%c\n", *c);  //<---to print the value that C is pointing
}
```

and when you call it you should pass the Address of ***a***

```
char a = 'a';
printf("a=%p\n", &a);
showString(&a);   //<---&a and not a
```

Comment: Hmmm: `printf("c=%p\n", &c);` ?  You want to print the address of `c`?

Comment: Note also, that if the to `printf()` calls are supposed to produce the same output, then the one in function `showString()` should print `c`, and `&c`.

Comment: Thanks. Inside the function, `c` has a different memory address than outside the function. But I see the function change to the variable carries outside of the function. How is that possible since inside the function, the variable has a different memory address?

Comment: @4thSpace The _pointers_ are located at different addresses, because you pass the _pointer_ by value i.e. copy. Both pointers, wherever they themselves are located, hold the same value at their respective locations, and that value is the address of the same `char`.

Comment: What remains unclear is the output is `"c=some_address\n"` and `"c=b\n"`, yet in both cases, neither is correct as `c` is a pointer and does not have the value of `&c` nor `*c`,

Comment: @chux `&c` prints the address of the pointer itself. `*c` prints the `char` that is located at the address given by the value of the pointer. But the value of the pointer, i.e. the address of said `char`, is not printed here: that would require printing just `c`.

Comment: @underscore_d Agree.  If I saw output `"c=0x1234\n"`, I would expect `0x1234` to be the value of `c` and not its address nor the value of what it points to.

Answer (score 6):

You are not using the pointer correctly: rather than assigning a new value to the object the pointer points to, you assign the pointer itself.

The call should use the address-of operator, and the assignment should be with the dereference operator:

```
showString(&a);
printf("a=%p\n", (void*)&a);
...
void showString(char *c){
    *c='b';
    printf("c=%p\n", (void*)c);
}
```

Now both printouts will produce the same address, and the value of `char a` in the calling function should change.

**Note 1:** The reason the compiler allowed `c = 'b'` assignment is somewhat odd: `'b'` is considered a character constant, `char` is considered an integral type, and C lets you assign integers to pointers with the assumption that you know what you are doing better than the compiler.

**Note 2:** When you print a pointer with `%p`, and the pointer type is neither `void*` nor `char*`, a cast to `void*` is required. You are printing `char*`, so it can go without a cast, but I added the cast anyway, in case you want to try this out with pointers of a different type.

Comment: They are _also_ not passing the pointer, but instead the value of the `char`.

Comment: Yes, but that's not a complete solution, because the OP also has an error in his function call.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah, you are right, I missed that completely. Thank you very much!

Comment: "You are printing `char*`, so it can go without a cast,'  Hmmm, although a pedantic point, a `char *` need not have the same width/layout as `void *`.  Highly portable code needs the `void *` cast to go with `"%p"`.

Comment: @chux That's odd - [C99 compiler with all warnings turned on and treated as errors does not mind me passing `char*` to `printf` with `%p`](http://ideone.com/YX2PqS). It [reports an error when I try to pull the same trick with an `int*` pointer](http://ideone.com/NZNiW8).

Comment: Likely that compiler will also not complain about printing `signed char*`,  `unsigned char*` with `"%p"`.  The C spec does say "The argument shall be a pointer to `void`."  I find no exception elsewhere in the spec that supports allowing `char*`.

Comment: @chux In C99 standard, 6.2.5, part 27, it says that "A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
pointer to a character type." That's why I think the compiler does not complain.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Interest [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289497/how-to-manipulate-variable-in-function/44289536?noredirect=1#comment75588299_44289536) and difficult to disagree with. I shall ponder that "same representation".